# Jenkins Multi Job Not picking up Test results from phase jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have configured a multi job that does the following :

- Phase 1

  - Clean
- Phase 2

  - Job 1

    - Update Workspace From SCM
    - Run Test
    - Get Test Report
  - Job 2

    - Update Workspace From SCM
    - Run Test
    - Get Test Report
- Phase 3

  - Display all Test Results.

Phase 1 and Phase 2 works, but the problem is, on Phase 3 it is unable to pick up the TestNG plugin results form the Job 1 and Job 2.

Note that Job 1 and Job 2 has it's own workspaces.

Any pointers on how the multijob aggregates the results?

Comment: The testng plugin AFAIK doesn't aggregate results.  It shows results based on run.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am having the exact scenario to solve.

Comment: Yup. The multi job does it, but have to use another plugin to aggregate the results. Its very hacky. I dont like it but works.